# If $f(x-2)=x$ for all real numbers x, then what is $f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

If $f(x-2)=x$ for all real numbers x, then $f(x)=?$ I think the answer stays the same, because the given says for all real x. so is $f(x)=x$ or i am wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602407/not-understanding-a-specific-substitution-rule/1602426#1602426.

Comment: If $f(x) = x$, then what is $f(t - 2)$?

Comment: We substitute x by t-2 and we get t-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x) = f(x + 2 - 2) = x + 2.$$

Comment: But it said for all real x? Do we not take it into consideration?

Comment: @Συλχαν  What must we do to $x - 2$ to obtain $x$?

Comment: Add 2 but i remember learning it somewhere when it says for all real x it doesn't matter what u plug in domain it will always be the same. Am I confusing this with something else?

Comment: @Συλχαν  Perhaps you are confusing this with a constant function.  Since $f(x - 2) = x$, the image of $f$ in this problem depends on the value of $x$.

Comment: It could be. Thank you.